# Trying to build a theme selector: But window closes abruptly

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

I am trying to create a theme selector for my notepad clone, using PySimpleGUI. I am first building the codes separately, and when it's working like expected, then I combine it in my main program. So the application window has:

1. Input Box
2. Listbox
3. OK button
4. Cancel button.

So all themes are listed in the Listbox, when I select any theme from that list, it should return the selected value, so I can set the theme of the main window to it. But the window keeps closing abruptly, so I used a popup() to display the selected theme name. But still, whenever I select a theme the window abruptly closes without any popup output. And there is no error because nothing shows in the terminal, so I can't understand what is the issue??

This is my application code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as pg

def main():
    theme_list = [
        'Black', 'BlueMono', 'BluePurple', 'BrightColors', 'BrownBlue', 'Dark', 'Dark2', 'DarkAmber', 'DarkBlack', 'DarkBlack1', 'DarkBlue', 'DarkBlue1', 'DarkBlue10', 'DarkBlue11', 'DarkBlue12', 'DarkBlue13', 'DarkBlue14', 'DarkBlue15', 'DarkBlue16', 'DarkBlue17', 'DarkBlue2', 'DarkBlue3', 'DarkBlue4', 'DarkBlue5', 'DarkBlue6', 'DarkBlue7', 'DarkBlue8', 'DarkBlue9', 'DarkBrown', 'DarkBrown1', 'DarkBrown2', 'DarkBrown3', 'DarkBrown4', 'DarkBrown5', 'DarkBrown6', 'DarkBrown7', 'DarkGreen', 'DarkGreen1', 'DarkGreen2', 'DarkGreen3', 'DarkGreen4', 'DarkGreen5', 'DarkGreen6', 'DarkGreen7', 'DarkGrey', 'DarkGrey1', 'DarkGrey10', 'DarkGrey11', 'DarkGrey12', 'DarkGrey13', 'DarkGrey14', 'DarkGrey15', 'DarkGrey2', 'DarkGrey3', 'DarkGrey4', 'DarkGrey5', 'DarkGrey6', 'DarkGrey7', 'DarkGrey8', 'DarkGrey9', 'DarkPurple', 'DarkPurple1', 'DarkPurple2', 'DarkPurple3', 'DarkPurple4', 'DarkPurple5', 'DarkPurple6', 'DarkPurple7', 'DarkRed', 'DarkRed1', 'DarkRed2', 'DarkTanBlue', 'DarkTeal', 'DarkTeal1', 'DarkTeal10', 'DarkTeal11', 'DarkTeal12', 'DarkTeal2', 'DarkTeal3', 'DarkTeal4', 'DarkTeal5', 'DarkTeal6', 'DarkTeal7', 'DarkTeal8', 'DarkTeal9', 'Default', 'Default1', 'DefaultNoMoreNagging', 'GrayGrayGray', 'Green', 'GreenMono', 'GreenTan', 'HotDogStand', 'Kayak', 'LightBlue', 'LightBlue1', 'LightBlue2', 'LightBlue3', 'LightBlue4', 'LightBlue5', 'LightBlue6', 'LightBlue7', 'LightBrown', 'LightBrown1', 'LightBrown10', 'LightBrown11', 'LightBrown12', 'LightBrown13', 'LightBrown2', 'LightBrown3', 'LightBrown4', 'LightBrown5', 'LightBrown6', 'LightBrown7', 'LightBrown8', 'LightBrown9', 'LightGray1', 'LightGreen', 'LightGreen1', 'LightGreen10', 'LightGreen2', 'LightGreen3', 'LightGreen4', 'LightGreen5', 'LightGreen6', 'LightGreen7', 'LightGreen8', 'LightGreen9', 'LightGrey', 'LightGrey1', 'LightGrey2', 'LightGrey3', 'LightGrey4', 'LightGrey5', 'LightGrey6', 'LightPurple', 'LightTeal', 'LightYellow', 'Material1', 'Material2', 'NeutralBlue', 'Purple', 'Python', 'PythonPlus', 'Reddit', 'Reds', 'SandyBeach', 'SystemDefault', 'SystemDefault1', 'SystemDefaultForReal', 'Tan', 'TanBlue', 'TealMono', 'Topanga'
    ]
    layout = [
        [pg.Input(key = '-theme select-')],
        [pg.Listbox(theme_list, enable_events=True, size = (45,15),key='-themes-')],
        [pg.OK(),pg.Cancel()]
    ]

    window = pg.Window('Theme Selector',layout,size = (400,400), modal = True)

    while True:
        event, values = window.read()

        if event == pg.WIN_CLOSED or 'Cancel':
            break
        
        elif event == '-themes-':
            selected_theme = values['-themes-']
            pg.popup(selected_theme)
            #window['-theme select-'].update(selected_theme)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the output:
[Theme Selector Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QbTCM.png)

When I select any theme from the list, it should show a popup that says the name of the theme selected.
But the window closes abruptly without any popup or output in the terminal.

Comment: `(event == pg.WIN_CLOSED) or 'Cancel'` will be always True, so break to close window all the time, try `event==pg.WIN_CLOSED or event=='Cancel'`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Theme selector that I wrote that I think is very handy.  Feel free to try it out.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg


def chooseThemePopUpLayoutCreater(startTheme):
    return [[sg.Frame('Select desired Theme from list below:',
                      [[sg.Column([[sg.T("")], [
                          sg.Combo(values=sg.theme_list(), size=(30, 8), default_value=startTheme, enable_events=True,
                                   key='-THEME-')]], vertical_alignment='t', element_justification='c'),
                        sg.VerticalSeparator(pad=None),
                        sg.Column([[sg.Text(f'Sample of Theme: {startTheme}')], [sg.Input("Data input field")],
                                   [sg.Input('Disabled input field', disabled=True)],
                                   [sg.Text('\nSlider:', expand_y=True),
                                    sg.Slider(range=(1, 10), default_value=5, orientation='horizontal')],
                                   [sg.Checkbox('Disabled Checkbox', disabled=True),
                                    sg.Checkbox('Checkbox', default=True)],
                                   [sg.Radio('Radio Button', 'RadioGroup', default=True),
                                    sg.Radio('Disabled Radio', 'RadioGroup', disabled=True)]])],
                       [sg.Button('Select this Theme'), sg.Button('Cancel')]], element_justification='c')]]


def chooseThemePopUp(startTheme='DarkBlue3'):
    origTheme = sg.theme()
    print(f"Started function chooseThemePopUp with startup theme:{startTheme} and current theme:{origTheme}")
    newTheme = None
    sg.theme(startTheme)
    window = sg.Window('Theme List', chooseThemePopUpLayoutCreater(startTheme), no_titlebar=True,
                       grab_anywhere=True,
                       finalize=True, keep_on_top=True, modal=True)
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event in (None, 'Cancel'):
            break
        elif event == '-THEME-':
            startTheme = values['-THEME-']
            sg.theme(startTheme)
            winX, winY = window.current_location()
            window.close()
            window = sg.Window('Theme List', chooseThemePopUpLayoutCreater(startTheme), no_titlebar=True,
                               grab_anywhere=True, location=(winX, winY), keep_on_top=True, modal=True, finalize=True)
        elif event == 'Select this Theme':
            newTheme = values['-THEME-']
            break
    window.close()
    sg.theme(origTheme)
    print(f"Reset theme to: {origTheme}")
    return newTheme

if __name__ == '__main__':
    theme = chooseThemePopUp()
    print(f"Theme select = {theme}")
```